# Bundle Exec Rake DB Migrate

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, devise, migration

I have been getting this error when I run bundle exec rake db:migrate for a basic RoR website. I am a beginner and found similar errors on this site and Treehouse but nothing with the specific second half of this error (from the NOT NULLC onward). I am still not sure how to resolve this - can anyone advise? I am running this on windows.

```
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "em
ail" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULLC:/Sites/code/omrails-master/db/migrate/201
30804201341_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
```

Comment: What are the contents of this migration file? Also what is your current database schema?

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting - I can try to clean that up...what is the database schema?

Comment: The text you've pasted is unreadable. Please use a service like pastie or gist.github.com.

Comment: Also what `rake db:migrate:status` outputs?

Comment: Here is the link to the migration file being referenced: http://pastie.org/private/wq4xxhgw7zpvlgg5kgunwg

Comment: Here is the link to the rake db:migrate:status output

http://pastie.org/private/rzew3hryfcmuwpssfhwtq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it happens because you already have the `email` column in your `users` table (a previous migration added it, propably that created the table) and the Devise migration you're running (`201
30804201341_add_devise_to_users.rb`) is trying to re-add it. Is that the case?

If so, open the migration file which first creates the `users` table and remove the line that creates the `email` column (it looks something like `t.string :email`). Close your Rails server, then do the following.

```
$ bundle exec rake db:drop
$ bundle exec rake db:create
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem when first starting out. I always solved it by just reseting the database. You already have a column created so reseting it will probably work.

run

```
bundle exec rake db:reset
```

than

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

and finally

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: are you familiar with drop_table inside of your migration?

Comment: Here is the output from running bundle exec rake db:reset

http://pastie.org/private/otkhgn4evfaflq8fo3rfya

Comment: I am not familiar with it.

Comment: actually are you on a windows?